# Is an example of a PDF $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ or $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\mathrm{d}t$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, intuition, density-function

The reason I ask is because according to this [source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F94ft.png):

> the $\fbox{$\color{blue}{\mathrm{PDF}}$}$ for the sum of two
>   Exponential Density Functions is
>
> $$\rho(x_1,x_2)\mathrm{d}x_1 \mathrm{d}x_2=\lambda e^{-\lambda 
>  x_1}\lambda e^{-\lambda x_2}\mathrm{d}x_1 \mathrm{d}x_2=\lambda^2 
>  e^{-\lambda(x_1+x_2)}\mathrm{d}x_1 \mathrm{d}x_2$$

So this implies that a PDF *must* be written in the form $$\rho(z)\mathrm{d}z$$ but this makes no sense as I thought that $\rho(z)$ **is** the PDF.

Now part c) of this [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjIVm.png) and [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92xn2.png) says that:

> the combined $\fbox{$\color{blue}{\mathrm{PDF}}$}$ for independent events is $$\lambda e^{-\lambda 
>  x_1}\lambda e^{-\lambda x_2}=\lambda^2  e^{-\lambda(x_1+x_2)}$$

This is clearly a contradiction as they can't both be correct. So which one is correct and why?

Thanks.

Comment: "So which one is correct and why?" The latter. The PDF is a *function*, which is the density of a *measure*. In the first formula in your post, $\rho$ is the PDF and $\rho(z)dz$ is (a somewhat relaxed notation for) the measure.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the clarification, there is another problem however; the last line of this [source](http://i.imgur.com/7WPEddD.png) says that the combined density is $\lambda^2 Xe^{-\lambda X}$ whereas this [solution to part c)](http://i.imgur.com/1LZXsSE.png) at the bottom says that the combined density is $\lambda^2  e^{-\lambda(x_1+x_2)}=\lambda^2  e^{-\lambda X}$. Which one is the correct joint density?

Comment: @Did any ideas?

Comment: The solution to part (c) relies on the undefined notion of combined density of some independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, by which the author seems to mean the function $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)$, where $f_{X_i}$ denotes the PDF of $X_i$, then states that this function is $f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)=g(x_1+x_2)$ for some function $g$. This is not true. Actually, $f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)=\lambda^2e^{-\lambda(x_1+x_2)}\mathbf 1_{x_1>0}\mathbf 1_{x_2>0}$, which does not depend on $x_1+x_2$ only $f_{X_1}(3)f_{X_2}(-1)=0\ne f_{X_1}(1)f_{X_2}(1)$ although $3+(-1)=1+1$. ...

Comment: ... Now, if the idea is to compute the density of $X=X_1+X_2$, observing that $f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)$ is what it is does not suffice. A simple approach is to note that for independent random variables, the PDF of the sum is the convolution of the PDFs, that is, $$f_X(x)=\int_\mathbb Rf_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x-x_1)dx_1,$$ which, in the present case, reads $$f_X(x)=\int_\mathbb R\lambda^2e^{-\lambda(x_1+x_2)}\mathbf 1_{x_1>0}\mathbf 1_{x-x_1>0}dx_1=\mathbf 1_{x>0}\lambda^2e^{-\lambda x}\int_0^xdx_1=\lambda^2xe^{-\lambda x}\mathbf 1_{x>0}.$$ One can note the automaticity of the procedure ...

Comment: ... when one does not omit the indicator functions from the PDFs. To sum up: *the PDF of a real valued random variable is a function defined on the whole real line and should be manipulated as such*.

Comment: @Did Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this to me, you produce very impressive results; you have answered every question I asked you. It really is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial sentence on the linked page is wrong.  The author is being sloppy with language.  The pdf in the first line is the *joint* pdf of the two random variables, not the pdf of the sum.  And it isn't even quite that.  The function
$$
\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda(x_1+x_2)} \quad\text{for }x_1,x_2>0
$$
is the probability density with respect to the measure $dx_1\,dx_2$.  One can then say that
$$
\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda(x_1+x_2)}\, dx_1 \, dx_2
$$
is the probability measure or the probability distribution (not to be confused with the cumulative distribution function, often called simply the "distribution function").

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there is another problem however; the last line of this [source](http://i.imgur.com/7WPEddD.png) says that the combined density is $\lambda^2 Xe^{-\lambda X}$ whereas this [solution to part c)](http://i.imgur.com/1LZXsSE.png) at the bottom says that the combined density is $\lambda^2  e^{-\lambda(x_1+x_2)}=\lambda^2  e^{-\lambda X}$. Which one is the correct joint density?

Answer (score 0):

The exponential distribution is part of the gamma distribution family, if $X$ has ${\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)}$ distribution:
$$
f_X(x)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}
$$
$\alpha$ is the shape parameter (more important) and $\beta$ is the scale parameter. The exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ is $\Gamma(1,\lambda)$, and it is easy to see, that the sum of $k$ exponentials has distribution $\Gamma(k,\lambda)$. So the first answer is incorrect, it should be
$$
f_{X_1+X_2}(y)=\lambda ^2 y e^{-\lambda y}
$$
They meant that
$$
f_{X_1+X_2}(y)=f_{X_1}*f_{X_2}(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_1}(t)f_{X_2}(y-t)\mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^y\lambda e^{-\lambda y}\lambda e^{-\lambda (t-y)}\mathrm{d}y
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, distribution theory is not my strong point, and I have never even heard of the gamma function. To keep it simple; If the PDF is given by $\lambda ^2 y e^{-\lambda y}$ what does it mean when you have $\lambda ^2 y e^{-\lambda y}\mathrm{d}y$ on it's own?

Comment: Well, if I understand your notation correctly, then $\lambda ^2 y e^{-\lambda y}\mathrm{d}y$ is the approximation of the probability that $X_1+X_2$ falls in the interval $[y,y+\mathrm{d}y]$  - so far that was the only way I seen it used in a probabilistic setting